# Права пользователя вне роли

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, role

Вопрос насчет permissions пользователя экземпляра sql сервера:

Например есть у нас пользователь Vasiok, за ним закреплена роль sysadmin. Возможно ли ему закрепить permission вне зависимости от роли?? То-есть, я хочу чтобы он себе и далее был только sysadmin-ом, но кроме того у него еще был дополнительный permission.

Если обобщить: могут ли существовать permissions отдельно от roles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> могут ли существовать permissions отдельно от roles?

Да, могут. И существуют.

В SqlServer есть иерархия разрешений. Разрешения сами по себе не зависят от ролей. Напротив - роль содержит некоторый набор разрешений (и/или запрещений). Есть встроенные роли, - такие как, например, *sysadmin*, - набор разрешений для них фиксирован и не может изменяться (т.н. *fixed roles*). Начиная с SqlServer 2012 можно создавать собственные роли уровня сервера, собирая в них необходимые наборы разрешений.

Логин может быть в какой-то одной роли, может быть в нескольких ролях одновременно, может не быть ни в одной роли<sup>(*)</sup>, и также может иметь разрешения, установленные напрямую, а не через членство в ролях.

Допустим есть логин

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [LoginName] WITH PASSWORD = N'L2RG9mZi6EZm'
GO
```

Можно сделать его членом роли сервера *sysadmin*

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [LoginName]
GO
```

но можно дать широкие права и явно

```
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [LoginName]
GO
```

Членство в роли *sysadmin* и право `CONTROL SERVER` эквивалентны<sup>(**)</sup>.

---

(*): строго говоря, любой логин всегда является членом специальной роли *public*, и отменить это нельзя.
 (**): на самом деле - почти (из-за [некоторых legacy вещей](http://www.insidesql.org/blogs/andreaswolter/2013/08/control-server-vs-sysadmin-sa-permissions-privilege-escalation-caveats)).

Comment: Спасибо за столь исчерпывающий ответ!